# How to use a specific older version of Ruby on Azure DevOps Pipeline?

Tags: ruby, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a project that needs to use Ruby with the exact version of `2.7.5`.

I tired using Azure's `UseRubyVersion@0` to install it:

```yaml
- task: UseRubyVersion@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: "2.7.5"
```

But this resulted in an error:

```
##[warning]Specifying an exact version is not recommended on Microsoft-Hosted agents. Patch versions of Ruby can be replaced by new ones on Hosted agents without notice, which will cause builds to fail unexpectedly. It is recommended to specify only major or major and minor version (Example: `2` or `2.4`)
##[error]Version spec 2.7.5 for architecture %s did not match any version in Agent.ToolsDirectory.
Available versions: /Users/runner/hostedtoolcache
2.7.7,3.0.5,3.1.3
```

As you can see, Azure only provides the latest patch of minor versions, so installing a specific version like `2.7.5` is not possible.

Is there an alternative way to install a specific version of Ruby in an Azure DevOps Pipeline?

Comment: Why do you need a specific older patch version? Why can't you use the latest? Btw. Ruby 2.7 will reach end-of-life in seven weeks anyway.

Comment: @spickermann It is the version required by `react-native`. I'm hoping using `2.7.7` might work as a temp fix. Either way, RN uses a Gemfile that lists a specific version of Ruby, so in the long run I don't want my builds breaking unexpectedly every time a new patch version is released. From what I understand the RN maintainers have intentionally decided to only support one specific version of Ruby at a time, so I'm hesitant to alter this.

Comment: Hmm, maintaining only one version at the time and then picking such an old version of Ruby that it will be unsupported by the Ruby maintainers soon is rough. Ruby 2.7 was released 3 years ago, I wonder why they never updated to 3.0, 3.1 or 3.2?

Comment: Well it's probably not a huge security concern since it's basically only being used for a local dev tool, but it is odd that they don't seem to be in a hurry to upgrade before support is dropped. I haven't been able to find any Github issues discussing why they can't upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

You must at least bump to the latest patch version of `2.7` that is `2.7.7`. `2.7.6` and `2.7.7` are bringing important security fixes, that's exactly why Azure does not allow old patch versions. You should take this seriously, this could cost your company to shutdown his activity.

More details:

- https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2022/04/12/ruby-2-7-6-released/
- https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2022/11/24/ruby-2-7-7-released/

Comment: That's good advice in general, but it also depends on the context. In my case I need the older version because `react-native` depends on it. Using outdated Ruby for a CI build of a mobile app is a lot different from using it to run something critical on the server-side.

Comment: Got it, I've submitted a PR to bump the ruby version here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/36074 let's see if it's merged at some point ;)

Comment: Haha. Well, good luck. I guarantee it will break things, but I like the optimism.

Comment: Indeed but it seems to have triggered interesting discussions: https://github.com/react-native-community/discussions-and-proposals/issues/594 :)

Comment: I saw that. One of the maintainers pointed me to your PR.  https://github.com/react-native-community/discussions-and-proposals/issues/594#issuecomment-1420476433